# JQuery for loop, wait for function to complete

Tags: jquery

I have code like this:

```
for(var hour = -1; hour > -24; hour--)
   $.getJSON(url + hour, function(data) {
      //...
   });
}
```

I need to use the hour variable in my getJSON function. But it goes through the for loop first. It does hour = -1, -2, -3... etc.

Then finally it does $.getJSON(url + -24). I want it to $.getJSON(url + -1), -2, etc and use that variable still inside the function.

Comment: It is actually making each call, but it does it asynchronously. You, apparently, want the processing to happen synchronously, which indicates that Javascript/AJAX may not be the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a recursive callback function like

```
function recurseJSON(hour) {
    if (hour < -24){
        return;
    }
    $.getJSON(url + hour, function (data) {
        //...
        recurseJSON(hour-1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the $.getJSON method is asynchronous. Your code doesn't wait until the for loop is over to make the $.getJSON calls; instead your code continues past the call before it has finished.

A way to fix this is changing the $.getJSON call to an $.ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax(
    url:url + hour,
    async:false,
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data) {
        //...
    }
});
```

$.ajax allows for adding `async:false` in there to make the ajax call synchronous.